# Adding yarn when using Typescript on Vue3

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, vuejs3

I am trying to follow https://yarnpkg.com/package/vue-disable-autocomplete to disable autocomplete in my vue3 project.

I ran yarn add vue-disable-autocomplete and added

```
import DisableAutocomplete from 'vue-disable-autocomplete';

Vue.use(DisableAutocomplete);
```

To my main.ts file, but I am getting the following error

[image]

Is there something I need to change because I am using Typescript

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is written in js and does not provide any type informations. You need to add a `[any name].d.ts` file in your project that looks like this:

```
declare namespace disableAutocomplete {
    function install(Vue: any): void;
}
```

This might not work but I can't comment your question, because I need 50 rep :)